# We cant access non static instance from a static method, but can initiate a class. how?

Tags: java

We cant access non static instance from a static method. But main() method is static and runs first. During initialization of any other class in main method, it will call the constructor. Is that constructor static ? what is the basic flow for JVM ?

Answer (score 4):

The *main* method is called by the JVM to run the method which is outside the scope of project.

When the JVM calls the `main` method, there is *no object* existing for the class being called. So it has to have *static* method to allow this from class.

Comment: we cant access non static variables and methods from a static method. and main is static. So, how we use all the other methods, classes and variables ?

Comment: I have read somewhere that JVM first create an Class class object. Is that true?

Comment: I advise you to go through [this chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html) in the JLS.

Comment: That's not to say there aren't instances of the class alive on the heap, but rather that
even if there are, the static method doesn't know anything about them.

Answer (score 1):

> During initialization of any other class in main method, it will call the constructor.

If you mean *instantiation*, then Yes it will.  Creating an instance of a class calls the constructor, whether the `new` call is made in `main` or anywhere else.

If you really do mean class initialization (which typically happens *implicitly*), then No it won't.  The initialization of a class does no involve the classes constructors.

For example

```
    public class Example {
        private static int foo = OtherClass.someMethod();
        static {
            // do something
        }
        public Example() {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

Class initialization executes the initializer for `foo` and the `static` initializer block, but is doesn't execute the constructor.  Creating an instance of `Example` calls the `Example()` constructor.

> Is that constructor static ?

Constructors are always static ... in the sense that `new` doesn't require an *existing* instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can't access non-static variables from static block because, non-static variable are instance variables & can only be accessed by creating an object of class with `new` operator or using reflection like `Class.newInstance()`. Whereas, static variables are class level & it's value is constant for every single object. It means no need to create an object of a class to access those variables. You can access static variable by using class name (different class) or directly (within same class) like :-

```
public class HelloWorld {
    private static String message = "Hello";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(message);
        System.out.println(HelloWorld1.sayHello);
    }
}

public class HelloWorld1 {
    public static String sayHello = "Hello1";
}
```

**main() method :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {}
```

In Java, main() method is static & it's the entry point of JVM. Since, **main() method doesn't belong to any class in Java**. When we define `main()` method in any user-defined class, then it will belong to that class. *And since it's static & within the same class, no need to access it using class name. The main method is directly available to JVM.*

**How JVM works :**

When there is need to execute to any Java class **ClassLoader** comes into picture. *The Java Classloader is a part of the Java Runtime Environment that dynamically loads Java classes into the Java Virtual Machine.*

[image: Java Code execution process]

**Image taken from :** [Understanding JVM Internals](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jvm-internals/#http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jvm-internals/)

When JVM starts to execute a Java file, it'll

1. First **compile** .java file & convert it into .class file which contains `bytecode` i.e, machine language or assembly language. Each time the same bytecodes are processed, **JVM works with JIT** (Just-In-Time) compiler to **convert byte code into native code**.
2. **Loads** the .java file & necessary packages **using System Class Loader & BoostrapperClassLoader** resp.
3. After loading, JVM will look into .class file & **store all information** like variables, packages, methods, etc & save them **into a memory & initialize all the field variables**.
4. The JVM then starts interpreting bytecode & displays the result of that in human readable form.